# C UTF8 string literals

Tags: c, string, string-literals

I have written a simple unit conversion function which returns the user unit as a string

```
typedef enum 
{
  Celsius,                    /**< Celsius °C - GRAD_C */
  Fahrenheit,                 /**< Fahrenheit °F - GRAD_F*/
}UnitType_T

#define UNITSTRING_MAXLENGTH  10   
typedef struct 
{
    UnitType eUnit;                             
    char szUnitString[UNITSTRING_MAXLENGTH+1];  /**< printable unit string with NULL-Termination, maximum length see UNITSTRING_MAXLENGTH */
} UnitStringComb_T;

static const UnitStringComb_T mg_units[]={
  {Celsius,"°C"},
  {Fahrenheit,"°F"}
};
```

However when i view the contents of mg_units in the debugger I'm getting
`Â°C`  and `Â°F`

When I copy the unitstring to a buffer, the output buffer also contains the `Â°F`/ `Â°C`

I know in C++ you can define [string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) but i haven found a solution for C.
Could you help me out here?

Thx :)

**Edit to clarifiy**
I'm reading the string using this function

```
const char* getUnitString(const UnitType_T unit)
{

  for(int i = 0; i < (int)(sizeof(mg_UnitString)/sizeof(mg_UnitString[0])) ; i++)
    {
      if(mg_UnitString[i].eUnit == eUnit)
      {
        return mg_UnitString[i].szUnitString;
    }
  return NULL
}
```

when calling this function the result contains the invalid chars mentioned previously.
This behaviour is seen on MSVC17 (Win 10) and GCC 10 (embedded Target).
On Windows VS 2022 is used as an IDE. On the target I see this letter on a LCD display

Comment: What are the values of the `char` elements of the arrays? If you want UTF-8, you should have `C2.B0.43.00` and `C2.B0.46.00`. The error is probably in how you're looking at them.

Comment: What is your compiler? What operating system are you using? What compiler options are you using? `when i view` What do you use to view? `in the debugger` Which debugger? `When I copy the unitstring to a buffer` How do you copy? `the output buffer` How do you check it? `I know in C++ you can define string literals` you can do the same in C.

Comment: You can always integrate the numerical value of the individual bytes into the string literal such as `"\x0d\x0a"` which is equivalent to `"\r\n"`. Sure, you have to calculate the bytes for the code point manually, but at least it would work...

Comment: Re "*I know in C++ you can define string literals*", The [equivalent C doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal)

Comment: If you integrate the characters into the literals directly make sure the source file is saved with utf-8-encoding as well. Be aware, too, that that if you try to print these utf-8 strings to console then the respective console needs to support this encoding as well (counter example: Windows cmd.exe!).

Comment: The issue here is likely that the editor you're using for your C source file is using a different multibyte convention than the environment where your code is running.  This is a common problem, especially on Windows.  That is, I'm guessing your editor (IDE) understands and renders UTF-8, and those string literals in your code `"°C"` and `"°F"` are encoded using UTF-8, but the environment where your program runs is *not* configured to use UTF-8.

Comment: Apparently the tools you use to view the UTF-8 encoded string interpret it as an 8 bit encoding, e.g. iso-8859-1, windows-1252 or similar.